# DatePicker Issue in Project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am having a project of one of my client. It has a datepickers in some of the pages. Actually
it is assigned to a property in model which is of datetime property.
Like here::

```
 [Display(Name = "Date Established")]
    public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }
```

Now it has been used in view as below::

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TargetDate , new { @Class = "datepicker" })
```

Please notice the class defined in the above textboxfor:: @Class = "datepicker"
Mere assigning that class to Textbox , it is converting the texboxt into datepicker.
I have checked and that class does not exists in the entire project. Is it jquery's Default functioanlity.As far as I know we have to convert it into datepicker in this manner
as described in Jquery::

```
 $("#PatientDOB").datepicker();
```

How can I track that class and change it so that it gives empty value by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay you are almost right just let me tell you that class = "datepicker" is nothing but usually class which we used commonly in our textbox . Just you need to do that in your view do as following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
})
```

and if you are giving any ID to your Textbox than you can do as following way.
Suppose your ID is ="idTargetDate" then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idTargetDate').datepicker();
})
```

This will work for you